# Why aren't network places visible with SharePoint 2001 and Office 2003?

Tags: office-integration, networking

Seems to be an age-old problem with SharePoint 2001 that you can't view the network places in Explorer if you have Microsoft Office 2007 installed.

As there seems to be no fix for this, Office 2007 was replaced with Office 2003, but the user still can't view the contents of a network place on SharePoint 2001. Any suggestions what might be leftover from Office 2007?

Comment: SharePoint 2001? Not sure if this a typo or not or if what I'm about to ask is silly... Are you asking about SharePoint Portal Server 2001 (v1) or SharePoint 2010 (v4)?

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with registry keys being left over when you downgrade office. The 12.0 references are still in somewhere, even though you are currently using office 2003.

I experienced similar problems when I beta tested SharePoint Designer 2010 on top of Office 2007 - it broke a few Office 2007 VBA macros.

I can't for the life of me remember which keys it was, but hopefully that should give you some direction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it still won't display the network locations... Removed Office 2003, then removed all the keys that are descibed in the following KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928218
Reinstalled Office 2003 and still no luck.

Comment: Deleting the registry keys didn't seem to help, had to reinstall XP and then install Office 2003 and SharePoint plugin.